# How to define Email Address on Journey with Filtered Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I have a `Appointment` object which has a Master-Detail relationship with an `Orders` object. In my Orders object sits a `Contact` lookup which relates to a subscriber.

I have created a Filtered Data Extension based on Appointments for my Entry Source in a Journey, in the Settings page it says there are no emails found in the Entry Source. How can I make Journey Builder look at the related object `Orders` for the `Contact.EmailAddress`?

Alternatively I've tried to simplifying the model by placing a Contact lookup in the `Appointment` object but the Settings page still says there are no email addresses found in the entry data.

Comment: You need to connect this event source de to you contact model in contact builder. Right now Journey builder can't make out how this relates to a contact/ subscriber

Comment: Hi ..how are you getting along? Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect your event source de to your contact model in contact builder. Right now journey builder can't figure out the relationship between that de and a contact